# Asp.Net MVC - Tracking an id in route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'd like to track an id in the route if it's possible? This is pretty much what I want:

```
/groups/{id} - Show group
/groups/{id}/forum/topic/{id} - Show forum topics for the group
/groups/{id]/calendar/ - Show the calendar for the group
```

As you see I want to keep track of what group the user is in by the url, instead of let's say a cookie.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined `{id}` in your routes, e.g.:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "", 
    "groups/{id}/forum/topic/{topicId}",
    new { controller = "Forum", action = "Topic" });
```

And into your controller:

```
public class ForumController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Topic(int id, int topicId)
    {

    }
}
```

It's not really clear how you want to track it....

Comment: I'm completely new to mvc so perhaps I should have studied some more before asking. It seems all I need to do is that when I create a link I keep passing the groupid (first {id} above). Now I'm just wondering how I can get the groupid within a view, to pass it on to for example ActionLink.

Answer (score 0):

This would work as long as all the possible Urls are generated with the Id. For these routes, you can access the {id} using the following:

```
int id = int.Parse(RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());
```

It may be cumbersome to ensure every link on each page contained the Id.  No static Urls would be allowed. For example, if the user clicked to the homepage or to /about, the Id would be lost.